# how to get whole object in laravel Eloquent with many tables?(Database Structure Updated)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Product Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name','brand_id','sort'];

public function brands() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Brands','brand_id');
}
public function sub_attributes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubAttributes','id');
}
public function values() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\AttributesValue','product_id');
}
```

**Main Attribute Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
public function sub_attribute() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubAttributes','main_attribute_id');
}
public function attributes_value() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\AttributesValue','App\SubAttributes');
}
```

**Sub Attribute Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name','main_attribute_id','filter'];

public function main_attribute() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MainAttributes','main_attribute_id');
}
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id');
}
public function attribute() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\AttributesValue','sub_attribute_id');
}
```

**Attribute Value Model**

```
public function sub_attribute() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubAttributes','sub_attribute_id');
}
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','id','product_id');
}
```

Database Structure:-
Table: Product
    id, name, brand_id
Table: main_attribute
    id, name
Table: sub_attribute
    id, name, main_attribute_id
Table: attribute_value
    id, product_id, sub_attribute_id, value
i want array of value by product id

Array [
product [
    id:10
    name:name of product
    brand:product brand
    main_attribute: [
      id:1
      name:product main attribute
      sub_attribute: [
        id:5
        name:main attribute have sub attribute
        main_attribute_id:1
        value: [
          id:id
          product_id:10
          sub_attribute_id:5
          value:some text
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]

I want get by **product id** -> *Main Attribute->Sub Attribute -> Attribute Value*

I am getting only values but now the whole object in sequential so please reply as soon as possible

Thank you in advance

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: Also try to add your database structure